# React: How to open PDF in new Tab from Cloud storage without downloading in local pc

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to open pdf from the cloud in a new tab, without downloading it to the local machine.

I tried this way but not working for me. In the new tab, it is giving an error.[image]

```
function readFileInNewTab (fileId) {
    let url = BASE_URL + "api/CMS/Documents/Download/" + fileId;
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', ...authHeader(url) },
        credentials: 'include',
        responseType: "blob", // important
    };
    inProgress = true;
    return fetch (url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse)
        .then((response)=> {
            const file = new Blob([response], { type: "application/pdf" });
            //Build a URL from the file
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            //Open the URL on new Window
            const pdfWindow = window.open();
            pdfWindow.location.href = fileURL;   
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, We can read pdf without downloading it?

Comment: How? I want to display it from browser.
Server is returning me baseb4